# SignalR maxes out cpu on app pool recycle

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr

I have a website written in .Net 4.5, MVC 4, using SignalR 2.0.2 with the Redis backplane for load balancing. This also has a number of actions to return json to the app. It's set to pre-load and app pool set to always running. Hosted on Windows 2012, IIS 8, using AWS Redis ElastiCache.

I am saving the connection ids into my SQL database against the user on the OnConnected, OnReconnected, and clearing with OnDisconnected, but these all have try/catch just in case.

We have an iOS app written to connect via websockets. Unfortunately the app does not close off it's connections and creates them more often than needed.

The net effect is that the server can have 3000+ connections, but only a few hundred are real connections. This is not really an issue in itself, and will be fixed in the next app release.

The problem is when the code is updated or the app pool recycles (regular intervals) the CPU maxes out for a long time. I have not had this happen with any other website i have written, and this is the first SignalR site with so many connections, so i believe that the server is trying to gracefully handle all the connections.

The effect is that the **whole website is unavailable**. Doing an IISRESET fixes it, obviously. Does not matter if the system is running on 1 server or 2.

So, knowing that this version of SignalR does not support disconnecting clients from the server-side...

1. Does anyone know why this would happen?
2. Is there anything i can do about it, except for killing the website with iisreset?

If any more info is required, please ask.

Long time reader, first time poster.
Thanks

Comment: What SignalR client are you using on iOS? How long is the CPU maxed out? This might partially be caused by all your clients trying to automatically reconnect once the server comes back up after the app pool recycle. Keeping a bunch of WebSockets open is pretty inexpensive, but establishing a bunch of WebSocket connections simultaneously is more costly. I would think that doing an IIS reset  would result in the same problem however.

Comment: Not sure of the iOS client used, i think it's a port of the MS one. CPU is maxed out longer than i want to allow for a live site, 4-5 mins is all i have allowed it to be down for.

Comment: I would take a look at your requests logs to see if the server is getting hammered or not.

Comment: So, did you find any solution?